# BULK INSERT WITH THE FILE NAME

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm bulk inserting csv files into this table,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XMLData]
(
    [id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col1] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [NCHAR](24) NOT NULL,
    [col3] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [col4] [XML] NULL,
    [fname] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [importedDate] [DATETIME] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [XMLData_pk] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The bulk format is

```
13.0
4
1       SQLCHAR            0       42      ","       2     col1 ""
2       SQLCHAR            0       48      ","       3     col2 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR            0       42      ","       4     col3 ""
4       SQLCHAR            0       0       "\n"       5     col4 ""
```

`[id]` is an identity column and `[fname]` is the file name that's bulk inserted into the table, I update the `[fname]` by the name of file that is just inserted right after a bulk insert, as below

```
DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT WHICHPATH, WHICHFILE 
     FROM @fileList 
     WHERE WHICHFILE LIKE '%.csv%'

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @path, @filename

WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
         BEGIN TRANSACTION 
             SET @sqlc = N'BULK INSERT [dbo].[XMLDATA] FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
             + '  WITH (FORMATFILE = ''' + @path + 'format.fmt''' + ',TABLOCK )';

             EXEC (@sqlc)

             UPDATE [dbo].[XMLData] 
             SET fname = @filename 
             WHERE fname IS NULL

             COMMIT
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH
        RAISERROR(N'The batch %s did not import!',-1,-1, @filename);   
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @path, @filename
END

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

I'm realizing the UPDATE after bulk insert takes longer than inserting itself.
Is there anyway to insert the filename with the file simultaneously to the column [fname] ?
And my second question is, does putting Bulk Insert into a TRANSACTION lower the performance?

Comment: On a different note to your question I would personally recommend using `QUOTENAME` on your string concatenation; just in case there are any odd characters, but also to ensure you avoid injection. For example `...FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@path + @filename,N'''') + N'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of BULK INSERT, and you can load your table with an INSERT … SELECT, and add columns.

Comment: I changed to OPENROWSET and it worked for some rows but not for all. One column (col4) stores a large XML data in it (>8000), I get this error for reading those large rows. 
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 19, column 4 col4